# Cos'è una "spilla francese"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Lila s’infilava sotto pelle la rugginosa **spilla francese** che aveva trovato per strada non so quando ma che conservava in tasca come il regalo di una fata; e io osservavo la punta di metallo che le scavava un tunnel biancastro nel palmo, e poi, quando lei l’estraeva e me la tendeva, facevo lo stesso.

Non so cos'è una "spilla francese". Ho cercato "spilla" e "francese" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato dell'espressione "spilla francese"?

Comment: Penso si riferisca semplicemente ad un spilla. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spilla_di_sicurezza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso anche io che si riferisca alla *spilla da balia* o *spilla di sicurezza*.
Su internet (http://lellobrak.blogspot.fr/2011/08/e-spingule-francese.html) ho trovato:

> [..]spingule francese significa(non letteralmente) spilla da balia
>   viene chiamata cosí perchè sono appunto spille che venivano usate nel ‘700 dalle balie per chiudere i pannolini di stoffa dei bambini
>   (viene chiamata spingule francese perchè sono stati appunto i francesi a portare la novità a Napoli)!

Essendo Elena Ferrante di Napoli mi sembra che la cosa torni. In ogni caso personalmente è la prima volta che sento il termine

Comment: Ho trovato questo [poema napoletano con la traduzione all'italiano](http://www.napoligrafia.it/musica/testi/eSpinguleFrancese.htm) nel quale "spíngule francese" viene tradotto come "spille da balia". Quindi sembra trattarsi di un'espressione di origine dialettale.

Comment: Appare anche [qui](http://www.pinoindini.it/s.html) e [qui](http://www.ponzaracconta.it/2011/02/09/alfazeta-voci-del-dialetto-ponziano-2-2/).

Comment: Occhio, che l'autore stesso del blog citato riporta quel brano come esempio di testo poco credibile, anche perché la spilla da balia fu inventata nel 1849, e non in Francia.

Comment: @DaG: La mia referenza non era intesa a supportare un'ipotesi sull'origine del termine, ma semplicemente a segnalare il fatto che apparentemente nella zona di Napoli la spilla da balia è chiamata anche spilla francese. Trattandosi di un termine dialettale è difficile trovare una referenza più ufficiale

Comment: Benissimo, era solo per chiarire.

Comment: E non è solo un poema ma una delle più famose [canzoni](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVvuKei-7NAhVGVhQKHSaKATIQtwIIHjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DpoUHV0zK5_8&usg=AFQjCNH101U5YVUuYckubQHXU6G9g1XRYA) della tradizione napoletana